# How to prevent a route from registering before jwt verifies react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jwt, react-router-dom

today I'm having an issue where react loads the route before my API verifies that the user's JWT token is valid. When using EJS I could pass in a middleware to the route and the middleware would not contain the next() parameter. As a result the server wouldn't render the EJS which is exactly what I want to achieve with react. Also is it possible to make useNavigate not reload when navigating the that specific route?

My routes in App.js currently look like this:

```
<Route element={<ProtectedRoute access={access}></ProtectedRoute>}>
  <Route
    path="/login"
    exact
    element={<Login login={login} access={access}></Login>}
  ></Route>
  <Route
    path="/signup"
    exact
    element={<Signup signup={signup} access={access}></Signup>}
  ></Route>
  <Route
    path="/forgot-password"
    exact
    element={<ForgotPassword access={access}></ForgotPassword>}
  ></Route>
  <Route
    path="/reset-password"
    exact
    element={<ResetPassword access={access}></ResetPassword>}
  ></Route>
</Route>;
```

The access function looks like this:

```
const access = async (token) => {
  return await axios.post(
    "http://localhost:5000/access",
    {},
    { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } }
  );
};
```

The protected route component looks like this:

```
import { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { useLocation, useNavigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import AuthContext from "../Context/AuthProvider";

const ProtectedRoute = ({ access }) => {
  const [authorized, setAuthorized] = useState(false);
  const { auth } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const authorize = async () => {
    try {
      await access(auth.accessToken);
      setAuthorized(true);
    } catch (err) {
      setAuthorized(false);
    }
  };

  authorize();

  if (authorized) {
    navigate('/');
  } else {
    return <Outlet></Outlet>;
  }
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

When I use this code my login component renders a bit before the code navigates back to the home page, how do I make the login component not render at all and just make it stay on the home page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

1. The `ProtectedRoute` component's initial `authorized` state masks the confirmed unauthenticated state, and since the component doesn't wait for authentication confirmation it happily and incorrectly redirects to `"/"`.
2. The `ProtectedRoute` component incorrectly issues a navigation action as an unintentional side-effect via the `navigate` function and doesn't return valid JSX in the unauthenticated case. Use the `Navigate` component instead.
3. If the user is authorized the `ProtectedRoute` should render the `Outlet` for a protected route to be rendered into, and only redirect to login if unauthorized.

## Solution

The `ProtectedRoute` component should use an indeterminant initial `authorized` state that doesn't match either the authenticated ***or*** unauthenticated state, and ***wait*** for the auth status to be confirmed before rendering either the `Outlet` or `Navigate` components.

Example:

```
import { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { useLocation, Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import AuthContext from "../Context/AuthProvider";

const ProtectedRoute = ({ access }) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [authorized, setAuthorized] = useState(); // initially undefined!

  const { auth } = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    const authorize = async () => {
      try {
        await access(auth.accessToken);
        setAuthorized(true);
      } catch (err) {
        setAuthorized(false);
      }
    };

    authorize();
  }, []);

  if (authorized === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return authorized
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace state={{ from: location }} />;
};
```

Move the login route *outside* the `ProtectedRoute` layout route.

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    path="/login"
    element={<Login login={login} access={access} />}
  />
  <Route
    path="/signup"
    element={<Signup signup={signup} access={access} />}
  />
  <Route
    path="/forgot-password"
    element={<ForgotPassword access={access} />}
  />
  <Route
    path="/reset-password"
    element={<ResetPassword access={access} />}
  />
  ... other unprotected routes ...

  <Route element={<ProtectedRoute access={access} />}>
    ... other protected routes ...
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

### To protect the login/signup/forgot/reset/etc routes

Create an `AnonymousRoute` component that inverts the `Outlet` and `Navigate` components on the authentication status. This time authenticated users get redirected off the route.

```
const AnonymousRoute = ({ access }) => {
  const [authorized, setAuthorized] = useState(); // initially undefined!

  const { auth } = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    const authorize = async () => {
      try {
        await access(auth.accessToken);
        setAuthorized(true);
      } catch (err) {
        setAuthorized(false);
      }
    };

    authorize();
  }, []);

  if (authorized === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return authorized
    ? <Navigate to="/" replace />
    : <Outlet />;
};
```

...

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<AnonymousRoute access={access} />}>
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login login={login} access={access} />} />
    <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup signup={signup} access={access} />} />
    <Route path="/forgot-password" element={<ForgotPassword access={access} />} />
    <Route path="/reset-password" element={<ResetPassword access={access} />} />
    ... other protected anonymous routes ...
  </Route>
  
  ... unprotected routes ...

  <Route element={<ProtectedRoute access={access} />}>
    ... other protected authenticated routes ...
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Comment: The protected routes are working find, however when I'm logged in I don't want the user to access those 4 unprotected routes, how would I manage to implement this?

Comment: @Yuuki Create an "AnonymousRoute" just like the `ProtectedRoute` but inverts the `Outlet` and `Navigate` components. In other words, if a user is authenticated then redirect them to a route that is ok for them to access, and if they are unauthenticated render the outlet so the login/signup/etc routes are accessible. Does this make sense? Let me know if you'd like me to update my answer with an example.

Comment: So basically I just copy the same exact code, but instead of redirecting to the login I'll redirect it to the home? I'd like to see an example just in case.

Comment: @Yuuki Something to also consider: I noticed you pass an `access` function to every component and route wrappers, it would much cleaner to include it in the `AuthContext` context so you aren't drilling it through as a prop to all the components. I'd even suggest not exposing the auth token directly like that and just exposing out an `access` callback from the context that closes over the current token value. Just a thought.

Comment: I removed using the access as now I have no use to pass it as a prop. What exactly do you mean that I'm exposing my auth token, and if I was how would I stop exposing it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245278/discussion-between-yuuki-and-drew-reese).